# How to detect RegOpenKey or RegSetInfoKey Event in C#

Tags: c#, events, registry, detect

im trying to detect the RegOpenKey or RegSetInfoKey event like Process Monitor from Mark Russinovich (Sysinternals) does.
Does anyone know how to write a C# Event which gets fired when a Program is doing a RegOpenKey or RegSetInfoKey on a RegistryKey (NOT changing!)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI. Read some example [here](http://objectmix.com/dotnet/108737-wmi-howto-monitor-registry-additions-only-registy-changes-only.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page: [Global System Hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx)

I believe that will accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is for Keyboard and Mouse. I don't see how this would help me get the registry events...